# This is a hard riddle

Tags: riddle

> I'm good for your house 
> I'm bad for your phone
>
> In the right form I can be worth a lot 
> In the wrong hands I can damage a lot
>
> Some people say they make me when scared
> Other people tend to hit me before they leave

So what am I?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

How about:

> **BRICKS**?

*I'm good for your house*
*I'm bad for your phone*

> Bricks are vital for building a house. A phone which is 'a brick' is heavy and unwieldy.
>
>  <sup>Also, as pointed out in comments by @postmortes, if a phone is '[bricked](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bricked)' it is broken and unusable.</sup>

*In the right form I can be worth a lot*
*In the wrong hands I can damage a lot*

> A gold brick is worth a large amount of money (and in the US, '[brick](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slang_terms_for_money)' is a slang term for $100,000). Meanwhile, a yob in the street could put a brick through your window...

*Some people say they make me when scared*
*Other people tend to hit me before they leave*

> Some people might '*brick it*' (or 'lay a brick') when scared (meaning their bowels might give way a little). '[Hit the bricks](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/hit_the_bricks)' is a phrase meaning 'to travel about'.

As for the title:

> Bricks are definitely hard!

Comment: I have never heard of the last one. Nice. +1

Comment: A phone which is bricked is unusable cf. https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bricked

Comment: I was thinking of a different form in which is worth a lot. I also had the anwser of @postmortes in mind

Comment: @postmortes Ah, yes - added, thanks :) Will keep thinking about OP's other point in comments...

Comment: @SirDuckduck Better now? :)

Answer (score 7):

Final Answer

> **GAS**

I'm good for your house

> Houses use gas to run appliances

I'm bad for your phone

> You shouldn't use your cellphone while pumping gas for your vehicle, could cause a fire

In the right form I can be worth a lot

> Gas can be a pricey commodity

In the wrong hands I can damage a lot

> Pouring gas on something will cause greater fire damage (arson)

Some people say they make me when scared

> Passing gas

Other people tend to hit me before they leave

> Hit the gas - telling someone to press the gas pedal in a vehicle

Title

> This riddle is hard because it contains a lot of gas within, like an air-filled ball.

Previous

> **LIGHTS**

Comment: Good try. Sadly not what I though off. Also the title is a hint, don't think you can make it match your answer :)

Answer (score 5):

Although, It doesn't apply completely throughout the riddle. This is my best guess.

I'm good for your house

> Household Water

I'm bad for your phone

> Water spoils the phone

In the right form I can be worth a lot

> Drinking Water

In the wrong hands I can damage a lot
???

Some people say they make me when scared

> Sweat

Other people tend to hit me before they leave

> Tear

Comment: my initial thought too..!

Answer (score 1):

I am a

> Road

I'm good for your house.

> Accessibility is crucial for a house.

I'm bad for your phone.

> Phone falling on the road

In the right form, I can be worth a lot.

> Well constructed roads

In the wrong hands, I can damage a lot.

> A poorly constructed road

Some people say they make me when scared. 
*(I am not sure about this one)*

> Roads are made when you are scared of **a)** accidents **b)** losing power if you are a politician

Other people tend to hit me before they leave

> Hit the road

As the title suggests,

> Roads are hard

Answer (score -2):

Is it:

> a dog ?

I'm good for your house:

> A dog can provide safety

I'm bad for your phone:

> A dog may break your phonew

In the right form I can be worth a lot:

> A dog can keep you safe and be a companion

In the wrong hands I can damage a lot:

> Some dogs can be quite dangerous

Comment: Hi Naresh - can you explain why you think this, please? With riddle questions on this site it's customary to show how a suggested answer satisfies each line (see the other answers for examples). Thanks :)